# Rendering a controller/template/route into another template

Tags: ember.js

This is probably a very common task, but I am not sure which is the right approach to tackle this.

I have a Route / Controller / Model setup that loads groups. In the header area before the main content I want to show notifications for the user. I have created a notificationcontroller that is an arraycontroller and as well as a route that loads all notifications.

I don't want this route to be used for anything else than within this area.

I have already tried in my groups.hbs to add an additional `{{ outlet notification }}` and try to render in it:

```
App.GroupsRoute = GambifyApp.BaseRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.get('store').find('group');
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('notifications', {   // the template to render
                // into: 'notifications',                // the route to render into
                outlet: 'notification',              // the name of the outlet in the route's template
                controller: 'notifications',       // the controller to use for the template
                });
        this.render('groups');
    }

});
```

But somehow my notifications template is not used. For now there is not much in my NotificationsController (It's an ArrayController) , NotificationsRoute is only reading all Notifications as Model and the template is currently only text, which is not rendered in my groups.hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template containing the outlet you want to render into must be rendered first in order to render into the outlet. Here is an example of rendering into a named outlet that is in the `application` template from the `index` route:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoyi/1/edit?html,js,output

Leave a comment if this example doesn't clear it up for you.

Comment: Ok I'll understand the difference, but I still would like to render the notification into my group template and not in my application template, because I only want to show it there. Is that possible too?

Comment: Sure. You just need to make sure you render the template for the route first, then render into the named outlet in it. Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoyi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it is working, the only question would be how I could also use the notifications route in order to get the model?

Comment: Good to here, m0c. I don't understand your question. In this approach, NotificationsRoute would not be used.

Comment: That is my issue, My Notifications Controller Template etc. has an own route which loads the models. In this scenario I have to manually fetch the model in the group model hook and set it on the notifications controller. I would like to define that the model should also be loaded from the notifications route. But I am not sure if this is possible at all.

Comment: That's not possible. If you want your notifications model to be looked up in the router layer and set on the notifications controller, and be present all the time in the app, it would be best to use the ApplicationRoute's model and setupController hooks to accomplish that.